# Laravel artisan command from controller

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I update my `.env` file using a function in my controller.
After I save the settings I need to update, I call `Artisan::call('config:cache')` to clear the cache of my site's configuration.

Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try to clear config cache on production, it doesn't work. (No warnings or errors.)
I even tried with `--no-interaction` option attached to this CLI command.

Did anyone have this problem and know what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

check into the PHP security settings and make sure you can run these `exec,passthru,shell_exec`   functions in your server.

Comment: or check permissions to cache folder